# Java library for multi-media and graphics

Tags: open-source, java, vector-graphics, opengl

I need to port to Java some apps that are targeted to mobile and desktop environments. They rely on either Cairo or Quartz2d (Linux or macOS), SDL and OpenGL.

Can anyone suggest me an open-source framework stack for Java that would:

- Offer 3D (OpenGL), 2D and multimedia support
- Be portable enough to support mobile devices and desktop

?

I looked into JMF, JavaFX, Java2D and bindings to non-Java libraries such as LWGL or jMonkeyEngine. JMF, JavaFX and Java2D seem to be on their way to deprecation (therefore support for new formats and devices would be at risk). On the other hand, I distrust JNI/JNA (VM crashes).

**EDIT**: As for plain 2D drawing, I have just realized that from Java 7 on there is a possibility for seamlessly replacing the rendering engine of AWT: [CacioCavallo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/caciocavallo/ng). I've thus decided to go with Java2D. Now my question, still mostly valid, reduces rather onto the 3D and multi-media axis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does not look as if this question were to be answered properly any soon, so I will just leave here my best effort to answer it.

As far as I have seen, I have two promising possibilities for 3D/OpenGL and multimedia support that are cross-platform (including mobile) and full-featured:

- [libGdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)
- [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/)

Since my needs are rather low-level, I think I will go with LWJGL.